# Debug SQLite in Chrome

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome, debugging, cordova

I'm developing a mobile app through phonegap, and I'm using the db.transaction function to handle the storage. Problem is, that when I try to debug in chrome (outside of the android emulator) I get an error that the method does not exist. How can I overcome this, so I don't have to recompile with every little change I make to my code?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome Remote Debugging. It gets you access to the WebSQL db's being used within your application, as well as the console so you can see more about your errors in general.